# Javascript ondrop is not doing anything

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out drag and drop, looked at a lot of tutorials and  questions but still when I drop my smiley face, nothing happens. I thought it would work because it works on the ondragstart.

HTML:

```
<div id='dragging'></div>
<img draggable ='true' src ="http://img87.imageshack.us/img87/5673/rotatetrans.png" id="smiley"/>
```

javascript:

```
var smiley = document.getElementById('smiley');
var dragging = document.getElementById('dragging');
smiley.ondragstart = function(){
  dragging.innerHTML = 'You are dragging!';
};
smiley.ondrop = function(){
  dragging.innerHTML=' ';
};
```

I also tried this:
javascript:

```
smiley.addEventListenter('ondrop',dragging.innerHTML=' ');
```

Comment: you add the ondrop event on the element you want items dropped on not the ones you drag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've read tutorial, but not the right ones, it seems.

In order for a `drop` event to be fired, you *first* have to cancel the `dragover` and `dragenter` events. Makes little sense, but that shoudl work:

```
document.ondragover = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
};
document.ondragenter = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
};
```

And like Patrick Evans noticed in the comments, you have to set the `drop` event listenter on a drop area, not on the dragged element itself. Might be the `document` as well:

```
document.ondrop = function(e) {
    dragging.innerHTML = ' ';
};
```

Here's an [article by Peter Paul Koch](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2009/09/the_html5_drag.html) about all this nonsense (warning: cussing ahead).

Comment: and dragenter should be as well

Comment: @PatrickEvans Yes, thanks, I was checking. It was a while since I had to deal with that mess :)

Comment: @Veronica because you still have the drop call set for the dragging item when it needs to be on the element that is getting dropped on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
dragging.addEventListenter('drop', function() {
    dragging.innerHTML=' Dropped '
}, false);
```

Instead of

```
smiley.addEventListenter('ondrop',dragging.innerHTML=' ');
```

Second argument to `addEventListener` is a function. The third arguments determine whether the event is to be captured during bubbling or not

And, assuming that drop operation occurs on the same div displaying the image

Comment: If you use `addEventListener`, you must pass `"drop"`, not `"ondrop"`.

Comment: drop call should be on the element being dropped on.

Comment: Oops. Missed that one. Thanks for the heads up. Fixing it

Answer (score 0):

Try following this
[w3schools drag and drop](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop)

#mickjguy

Comment: do not reference w3schools, they are not a reputal source

Comment: That's me told - Hey, it works and should put aliasm2k on the right track.